# Validate HTML tags if they are valid HTML tag or not python?

Tags: python, django

I am using Django to build website and I want to check if I am using a valid HTML tag or not.
This is my code.

```
class Actions:
    view_class = None
    action_name = None
    action_code = None
    action_icon = None
    action_attr = None
    action_title = "icon"  # icon,text ,both
    with_url = False
    actions_template = "core/core/actions/action.html"
    action_css = []
    action_js = []
    action_class = "btn btn-secondary hide action-item"
    action_position = "above_form"  # above_form, above_grid, both ,on_form , on_grid
    action_tag = "a"

    def render_actions(self, request):
        return render_to_string(
            self.actions_template,
            {
                "action_name": self.action_name,
                "action_code": self.action_code,
                "action_icon": self.action_icon,
                "action_class": self.action_class,
                "action_title": self.action_title,
                "action_tag": self.action_tag,
                "with_url": self.with_url,
                "action_attr": self.action_attr,
                "with_modal": self.with_modal,
                "form_name": form_name,
                "action_url": reverse_lazy(self._related.__class__.__name__.lower()) if self.with_url else "",
            },
        )
```

For example if `action_tag` value is `buttun` the code should raise error, if `action_tag` value is `button` or any valid HTML tag there is no error raised.
How can I do this offline not online.

Comment: Are you looking for something like `if action_tag in ('a','input','button','img','div'):`?

Comment: Yes, I am but I want to check all html tags.

Comment: List of HTML tag references https://htmldog.com/references/html/tags/ and https://www.w3schools.com/tags/default.asp

Answer (score 1):

First of all, you can store a list of all the html tags in a `constants.py` file:

```
html_tags = ['<html>', '<base>', '<head>', '<link>', '<meta>', '<style>', '<title>', '<body>', '<address>', '<article>', '<aside>', '<footer>', '<header>', '<h1>', '<h2>', '<h3>', '<h4>', '<h5>', '<h6>', '<main>', '<nav>', '<section>', '<blockquote>', '<dd>', '<div>', '<dl>', '<dt>', '<figcaption>', '<figure>', '<hr>', '<li>', '<ol>', '<p>', '<pre>', '<ul>', '<a>', '<abbr>', '<b>', '<bdi>', '<bdo>', '<br>', '<cite>', '<code>', '<data>', '<dfn>', '<em>', '<i>', '<kbd>', '<mark>', '<q>', '<rp>', '<rt>', '<ruby>', '<s>', '<samp>', '<small>', '<span>', '<strong>', '<sub>', '<sup>', '<time>', '<u>', '<var>', '<wbr>', '<area>', '<audio>', '<img>', '<map>', '<track>', '<video>', '<embed>', '<iframe>', '<object>', '<param>', '<picture>', '<portal>', '<source>', '<svg>', '<math>', '<canvas>', '<noscript>', '<script>', '<del>', '<ins>', '<caption>', '<col>', '<colgroup>', '<table>', '<tbody>', '<td>', '<tfoot>', '<th>', '<thead>', '<tr>', '<button>', '<datalist>', '<fieldset>', '<form>', '<input>', '<label>', '<legend>', '<meter>', '<optgroup>', '<option>', '<output>', '<progress>', '<select>', '<textarea>', '<details>', '<dialog>', '<menu>', '<summary>', '<slot>', '<template>']
```

I wrote this one by using [this page](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element) (without the deprecated elements, but you can add them).

Then you can easily raise an exception if your action tag is not in that list:

```
if action_tag not in html_tags:
    raise ValueError('Not a valid html tag.')
```